Is there function that compares two ranges and returns the number of cells that changed values
I have two ranges and I want to count how many values have changed between them. I am trying to find a function that compares the two ranges and returns the number of cells that change. I know I could do a countif and then sum that but I am looking to get the answer in a single cell.
I am looking to be able to count the highlighted cells, which in this case is 20.


As in changed position, or changed value? Would Sheet1 {A,B,C,D} and Sheet2 {A,C,D,B} result in 3 changes, or none? Please show some examples.

=sumproduct(--(Range1 <> Range 2)) works
Range1 <> Range2 returns a bunch true/false values and the -- turns it into 0,1 values
